# How do you erase a label in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, label

When you create a label control in JavaFX, how do you erase it during an event of i.e. a button click? Here is how I created my Label:

```
        Label result= new Label("The result is ...");
        root.add(result, 0, 1);
```

I tried overwriting it with:

```
        Label result= new Label("");
        root.add(result, 0, 1);
```

But it doesn't make the previous text go away. It only overwrites the text on the pane.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you do this:

```
Label result= new Label("");
```

You are creating a new `Label` object. The `result` is just a variable that points to an object of type `Label`. Every time you use the keyword `new` you are creating a new object in the heap, but you are not deleting the old one, that's why it overwrites the text on the pane.

Instead of creating a new Label every time that you want to change the text, create a `Label` only once, and change the text of this existing `Label` object by doing this:

```
result.setText("");
```

Put this inside of the button's listener:

```
button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        result.setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to erase the *content* of the label, do:

```
final Label result = ...
root.add(result, 0, 1);

button.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
        result.setText("");
    }
});
```

You can alternatively *remove* the label; replace the `setText()` call with:

```
        result.getParent().getChildren().remove(result);
```

You may add it again later.

In any case, it has to be final, if declared inside the method. If it is a class member variable, it is OK without final.